# Finding data patterns in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I currently have a industrial gas generator which is datalogged to a Postgres server. One of the vessels in the generator is rated to be pressure cycled up to 10,000 times.

Is there a SQL example or method to show the number of times the pressure of the vessel (which is datalogged every second) has cycled between say, 10 bar and 100 bar?

EDIT based on a comment below:

Table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE log_934 (datetime timestamp primary key, pt001 real, pt002 real ...);
```

The data is inserted into the table via an external program every second where the 'pt' values are pressures. The equivalent INSERT commands would be:

```
INSERT INTO log_934 (datetime, pt001, pt002 ... ) VALUES ('2015-05-10 10:00:00', 50.65, 75.54 ...);
INSERT INTO log_934 (datetime, pt001, pt002 ...) VALUES ('2015-05-10 10:00:01, 50.69, 75.49 ...);
...
```

The expected outcome would be:

```
|pt001 cycled between 10 and 100|
---------------------------------
|50                             |
```

Comment: Please post the table definitions (as `CREATE TABLE`)  some sample data (e.g. as `INSERT INTO` statements) and the expected output based on that sample data.

Comment: What do the columns (pt001, pt002, ...) stand for? Are they sensors in the gas generator? What is a pressure cycle? Is that going from a value of 10 bar to 100 bar, or are you looking for any reading within that range, for each of the columns? And what does the 50 in the outcome stand for?

Comment: yes, PTs are pressure sensors in the plant. A pressure cycle is when the pressure value goes from 10 to 100 or vice versa. The outcome value, 50, would show that the generator has gone from 10 to 100 or 100 to 10 ... 50 times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first approach:

```
select count(*) from (
    select distinct max(lmin.datetime) as inflexion
    from log_934 lmax
    inner join log_934 lmin on lmax.datetime > lmin.datetim and 
                               lmin.pt001 <= 10
    where lmax.pt001 >= 100
    group by lmax.datetime

    union all

    select distinct max(lmax.datetime) as inflexion
    from log_934 lmin
    inner join log_934 lmax on lmin.datetime > lmax.datetim and 
                               lmax.pt001 >= 100
    where lmin.pt001 <= 10
    group by lmin.datetime
) T
```

First subquery get de <10 datetime for each >100 datetime read. Second one do the inverse. Then count how many datetimes found. See it in this pretty [d3js](http://d3js.org/) viz:

[image]